# how to concat two d.f like key and value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, concatenation

i got two df and i use python and pandas
[df 1+df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrR33.png)

```
df1 names  number
    dan    25
    alex   30
    tommy  28

df2 =  names  year color
    david  1980 red
    tommy  1956 blue
    albert 1774 blue
    alex   2034 red
    tommy  1922 blue
    dan    1990 red
    dan    2000 red
```

df1 is like a key because df2 had more than one the df1 index

**how can i concat (df1,df2) to have this df?**

[df_i would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIKB5.png)

```
df_new     names  year color number
           david  1980 red   nan
           tommy  1956 blue  30
           albert 1774 blue  nan
           alex   2034 red   28
           tommy  1922 blue  30
           dan    1990 red   25
           dan    2000 red   25
```

i try to do that

`df1=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')`

and i get `ValueError: Shape of passed values`

Comment: Please post dataframe as text instead of images.

Comment: In `df1`, the number associated with `tommy` is 28. While in `df_new` with `tommy`, the number associated is `30`. Can you explain the logic behind it? And same is the case for `alex`. Did you wrote the dataframe wrong or is there is any logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Use the join method for the new dataframe
df_new=df2.join(df1)
print(df_new)
```

output:

```
        year color  number
names                     
albert  1774  blue     NaN
alex    2034   red    30.0
dan     1990   red    25.0
dan     2000   red    25.0
david   1980   red     NaN
tommy   1956  blue    28.0
tommy   1922  blue    28.0
```

Comment: That's not the expected output.